# IIS deploy php application in subfolder of ASP.NET core NOPCommerce

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce-4.0

In NopCommerce 4.0 application I am trying to deploy an PHP application in subfolder.

So that the URL for subfolder is like `mydomain.com/blog/`.

I have added only one file to the blog folder as index.php.
I want the url for this page to be `mydomain.com/blog/index.php`.

Please note that I have already remove the blog from the RouteProvider.cs.
How can I process the index.php in the NOP 4.0 folder?

Comment: You can add a sub-application under your IIS website with alias `blog` and then map this website to your `blog` folder. Then, try to browse to  mydomain.com/blog/index.php. I am assuming you have PHP installed on your server.

Comment: I have tried this also but it is still not loading the php file and showing the 404 error page.

Comment: Have you checked the sub-application `Handler Mappings` in IIS Manager? Is `*.php` listed there?

Comment: Yes for PHP it is PHP_via_FastCGI and PHP53_via_FastCGI

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue solved by removing the route from the code and adding the below code in the web.config of the sub-folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>            
        <handlers>
          <remove name="aspNetCore" />
       </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, thanks!